# how to add a new Boolean column if all rows are NULL?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
Out[8]: 
   0    1    2
0  0    1.0  2.0
1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  0    0.0  NaN
3  0    1.0  2.0
4  0    1.0  2.0
```

I want to add a new Boolean column "abc" that if the row has all NaN, the "abc" is "true", otherwise the "abc" is "false", for example:

```
   0    1    2      abc
0  0    1.0  2.0    false
1  NaN  NaN  NaN    true
2  0    0.0  NaN    false
3  0    1.0  2.0    false
4  0    1.0  2.0    false
```

here is my code to check the row

```
def check_null(df):
        return df.isnull().all(axis=1)
```

it returns part of what I want:

```
check_null(df)
Out[10]: 
0    false
1    true
2    false
3    false
4    false
dtype: bool
```

So, my question is, how can I add 'abc' as a new column in it?
I tried

```
df['abc'] = df.apply(check_null, axis=0)
```

it shows:

> ValueError: ("No axis named 1 for object type ", 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Don't use apply, just assign directly: `df['abc'] = df.isnull().all(axis='columns')`

Comment: `df['abc'] = check_null(df)`

Comment: As your function is one liner, you can might very well do: `df['abc'] = df.isnull().all(axis=1)`.

Answer (score 4):

using `isna` with `all`

```
df.isna().all(axis = 1)
Out[121]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

And you do not need apply it

```
def check_null(df):
    return df.isnull().all(axis=1)
check_null(df)
Out[123]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

If you do want `apply` it you need change your function remove the `axis= 1`

```
def check_null(df):
    return df.isnull().all()
df.apply(check_null,1)
Out[133]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: This code is already in the question, I think the question is more about applying it

Comment: Thanks. One more question: What if I only check NaN value for the last 2 columns?

Comment: @potentialwjy df.iloc[:,-2:].apply(check_null,1)

Comment: Thanks. I just figured it out in a similar way. Thanks anyway